# Spring MVC links

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url, jboss

Im trying to create some website from scratch using Spring MVC (I have experience on PHP). There's something that bothers me about linking. This is my header

```
<span class="menu">
  <a href="/keep/projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="/keep/tasks">Tasks</a>
  .....
</span>
```

Keep is the name of my projects. I suspect that hardcoding it in url's is a bad practice. How can I avoid it? Also i'd like jboss to use just "http://localhost/" instead of "http://localhost/keep/" for my app. One more thing I think about, maybe I should use some jsp or spring links instead of usual html ones?

Answer (score 1):

First use Taglib
`<%@ taglib prefix="springTag" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>`

Make a URL Like this:-

`<springTag:url value="/myResources/resource/.." var="resource" />`

Please try to access this url like this:-

`<a href="${resource}">Projects</a>`

Comment: whats the difference between usual link and spring one? I would be able to skip "/keep" part and add some spring extra features in future?